# STM32L451CET6 ThreadX: Hard Fault when Creating Tasks over 27KB

Tags: stm32, threadx

Using STM32L451CET6 and threadx I created multiple task and was running into hard fault on debugging found that from my 70KB byte pool when i created a task more than 27Kb it was running into hard fault again
the usable memory is 160Kb out of which a partition exists between sram 1 and sram 2 which is of 128kb sram1 and rest sram2
Can anyone suggest why this is happening

Tried changing stack size of tasks, whenever they are under 27/28Kb they work perfectly. but when it is exceeding that limit,it runs into hardfault

Comment: don't know this platform or if it's relevant, but it sounds like memory fragmentation.  either this allocating a structure this big fails and doesn't handle the case well, or allocating something this large causes a subsequent allocation to fail